# How do I know if mappers(or reducers) are running in parallel in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I am currently running some MapReduce jobs on a Hadoop - 2.3.0 cluster with 8 slave nodes, but the jobs are taking longer than expected time to execute.

How do I test whether the map(or reduce) tasks are running in parallel?

And what are some properties that have to be modified in the configuration files so that Mappers(in this case 8 of them) are run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You should check in the Hadoop cluster web interface.

Go to the url which track your job status, look for a line which looks something like this one:

15/04/11 17:29:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hadoopsrv:60540/proxy/application_1428349332728_0303/

This web page displays the job status (succeeded/failed...), time for each task to complete, number of map/reduce tasks and their status, logs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop comes with several web interfaces which are by default available at these locations:

http://namenode1_server_ip_address:50070 -Web UI for HDFS namenode1
http://namenode2_server_ip_address:50070 -Web UI for HDFS namenode2
http://resource_manager_server_ip_address:8088 – Web UI for MapReduceJobTracker
http://job_history_server_ip_address:19888 – Web UI for TaskTracker

By using these all web user interface you can check the status of all hadoop mapper,reducer, active namenode, datanodes, etc.